# Publish Android App for Phone and Watch in Play store

Tags: android, google-play

I'm implementing Same App for  Android Phone and Watch .Both are having same package name.How to upload both apps in Play store?

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Multi-APK delivery method.

As per documentation:

> To make your app appear in the on-watch Play Store, you upload the
>   watch APK in the Play Console just as you would any other APK. If you
>   only have a watch APK and no phone APK, no other steps are required.
>   If you have a phone APK in addition to a watch APK, you must use the
>   Multi-APK delivery method.

Reference:

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging

https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks

Comment: How I Should I make versioning for Phone and Wear App?.

Comment: APK will be automatically filtered by using <uses-feature> ?